# C# internal bool? variableName; what does it mean

Tags: c#

I am new to C#, recently, I have noticed that Visual Studio generated the following line of code:

```
internal bool? variableName;
```

I tried to search on this forum and other sources on the meaning of the question mark, but couldn't seem to find anything. Could someone explain to me what does the ? represents.

Comment: It indicates that `variableName` has a third state of `null` rather than just `true` and `false`.

Comment: It's a [nullable value type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/nullable-value-types)

Comment: `internal` means its can only be access from that project, `bool` is a boolean `?` means its nullable, `variableName` is well a variable name

Comment: [Learn from the horse's mouth.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called nullable value type. Refer official documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/nullable-value-types).

```
using System;

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
      bool? s = null;
      int? g = null;
    
        // bool ss = null; // => compilation error
        // int gg = null; // => compilation error
    }
}
```

It lets you assign "null" to a type in addition to it's allowed values.

**internal** is access modifier. From the [official docs.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/internal)

> Internal types or members are accessible only within files in the same assembly

Comment: It's not called a "null conditional operator". You've linked to the wrong documentation. Actually both links you've posted are wrong.